How to set up Postgresql pglogical replication on the same database instance
I am trying to assess pglogical replication usage instead of the built-in one (particularly due to being able to filter by operation). I am using a single Azure Postgresql flexible server database instance where I have created two databases (main and replica).
I have done the following setup:
Main database
SELECT pglogical.create_node(
    node_name := 'main_node',
    dsn := 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=main user=x password=***'
);

-- check that the node is there
SELECT * FROM pglogical.node;

SELECT pglogical.create_replication_set(
    set_name := 'custom_set',
    replicate_insert := true,
    replicate_update := true,
    replicate_delete := false
);

-- start with a single replicated table
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table('custom_set', 'public."Message"');

-- check the configuration
select * from pglogical.tables
select * from pglogical.replication_set
select * from pglogical.replication_set_table

-- or better with
SELECT rs.set_name, n.nspname AS schema_name, c.relname AS table_name
FROM pglogical.replication_set_table rst
    JOIN pg_class c ON rst.set_reloid = c.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
    JOIN pglogical.replication_set rs ON rst.set_id = rs.set_id
WHERE rs.set_name = 'custom_set';

I have about 10K rows in the public."Message" on the main database.
Replica
SELECT pglogical.create_node(
    node_name := 'replica_node',
    dsn := 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=replica user=x password=*'
);

SELECT pglogical.create_subscription(
    subscription_name := 'main_to_replica_subscription',
    provider_dsn := 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=main user=x password=*',
    replication_sets := ARRAY['custom_set']
);

-- check the objects
SELECT * FROM pglogical.subscription;

-- this shows 'streaming'
SELECT * 
FROM pglogical.show_subscription_status();

The initial data is replicated fine. However, when inserting more data in the main table things begin to go astray:

the replication status is sometimes catching up or replicating and does not seem to end (come back to streaming).
the replication speed seems to be very slow (I expect sub-100ms for such low data volumes)
the following query indicates a growing number of bytes to be replicated

SELECT application_name, 
       state, 
       pg_current_wal_lsn() AS current_wal_lsn,
       replay_lsn,
       pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn) AS bytes_pending
FROM pg_stat_replication


database connections seem to be randomly dropped (e.g. pgAdmin begin reporting that the connection to the server was lost). This issue disappears if the subscription is disabled.

I assume there is something wrong with the setup when done on the same database instance. Is there any workaround?
select version() reports: PostgreSQL 15.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit.
Notes: I know from setting up the builtin PostgreSQL replication, that using the same instance required an explicit logical slot to avoid the replication getting stuck:
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('custom_slot', 'pgoutput');

However, I cannot find a similar workaround for the pglogical replication.
On a very similar setup (the same database instance), the builtin replication worked with the workaround mentioned above.
Relevant PostgreSQL server logs
The only error related to pglogical I could find in the server logs looks like this:

...-LOG:  starting pglogical database manager for database replica
...-LOG:  received replication command: CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL
pglogical_output","statement": "CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL
pglogical_output
...-LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at
314/E005A1F0","detail": "There are no running
transactions.","statement": "CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL
pglogical_output
-LOG:  exported logical decoding snapshot: "0000001B-000006BE-1" with 0 transaction IDs","statement": "CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL
pglogical_output
-LOG:  received replication
command: START_REPLICATION SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL 314/E005A228
(expected_encoding 'UTF8', min_proto_version '1', max_proto_version
'1', startup_params_format '1', "binary.want_internal_basetypes"
'1', "binary.want_binary_basetypes" '1',
"binary.basetypes_major_version" '1500', "binary.sizeof_datum"
'8', "binary.sizeof_int" '4', "binary.sizeof_long" '8',
"binary.bigendian" '0', "binary.float4_byval" '0',
"binary.float8_byval" '1', "binary.integer_datetimes" '0',
"hooks.setup_function" 'pglogical.pglogical_hooks_setup',
"pglogical.forward_origins" '"all"',
"pglogical.replication_set_names" 'custom_set',
"relmeta_cache_size" '-1', pg_version '150007', pglogical_version
'2.4.2', pglogical_version_num '20402', pglogical_apply_pid
'10812')","statement": "START_REPLICATION SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL 314/E005A228
(expected_encoding 'UTF8', min_proto_version '1', max_proto_version
'1', startup_params_format '1', "binary.want_internal_basetypes"
'1', "binary.want_binary_basetypes" '1',
"binary.basetypes_major_version" '1500', "binary.sizeof_datum"
'8', "binary.sizeof_int" '4', "binary.sizeof_long" '8',
"binary.bigendian" '0', "binary.float4_byval" '0',
"binary.float8_byval" '1', "binary.integer_datetimes" '0',
"hooks.setup_function" 'pglogical.pglogical_hooks_setup',
"pglogical.forward_origins" '"all"',
"pglogical.replication_set_names" 'custom_set',
"relmeta_cache_size" '-1', pg_version '150007', pglogical_version
'2.4.2', pglogical_version_num '20402', pglogical_apply_pid '10812')
-LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b"","detail":
"Streaming transactions committing after 314/E005A228, reading WAL
from 314/E005A1F0.","statement": "START_REPLICATION SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL 314/E005A228
(expected_encoding 'UTF8', min_proto_version '1', max_proto_version
'1', startup_params_format '1', "binary.want_internal_basetypes"
'1', "binary.want_binary_basetypes" '1',
"binary.basetypes_major_version" '1500', "binary.sizeof_datum"
'8', "binary.sizeof_int" '4', "binary.sizeof_long" '8',
"binary.bigendian" '0', "binary.float4_byval" '0',
"binary.float8_byval" '1', "binary.integer_datetimes" '0',
"hooks.setup_function" 'pglogical.pglogical_hooks_setup',
"pglogical.forward_origins" '"all"',
"pglogical.replication_set_names" 'custom_set',
"relmeta_cache_size" '-1', pg_version '150007', pglogical_version
'2.4.2', pglogical_version_num '20402', pglogical_apply_pid '10812')
...-LOG:  connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=43598 2024-10-16
07:54:21 UTC-670f712d.3189-LOG:  connection authenticated:
identity="CN=azuresu.b32b9622594c.database.azure.com" method=cert
(/datadrive/pg/data/pg_hba.conf:9) ...-LOG:  connection authorized:
user=azuresu database=postgres application_name=psql SSL enabled
(protocol=TLSv1.3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256)
...-LOG:
disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.165 user=azuresu
database=postgres host=127.0.0.1 port=43598
...-LOG:  disconnection:
session time: 0:00:20.997 user=azuresu database=postgres
host=127.0.0.1 port=51290
...-LOG:  connection received:
host=127.0.0.1 port=39900
...-LOG:  connection authenticated:
identity="CN=azuresu.b32b9622594c.database.azure.com" method=cert
(/datadrive/pg/data/pg_hba.conf:9)
...-LOG:  connection authorized:
user=azuresu database=postgres SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.3,
cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256) 2024-10-16 07:54:30
UTC-670f7122.313b-LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:20.044
user=azuresu database=azure_maintenance host=127.0.0.1 port=51300
...-LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by
peer","context": "slot
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b", output plugin
"pglogical_output", in the change callback, associated LSN
314/E43B3278","statement": "START_REPLICATION SLOT
"pgl_localdev3d6043b_main_node_main_to_0246a7b" LOGICAL 314/E005A228
(expected_encoding 'UTF8', min_proto_version '1', max_proto_version
'1', startup_params_format '1', "binary.want_internal_basetypes"
'1', "binary.want_binary_basetypes" '1',
"binary.basetypes_major_version" '1500', "binary.sizeof_datum"
'8', "binary.sizeof_int" '4', "binary.sizeof_long" '8',
"binary.bigendian" '0', "binary.float4_byval" '0',
"binary.float8_byval" '1', "binary.integer_datetimes" '0',
"hooks.setup_function" 'pglogical.pglogical_hooks_setup',
"pglogical.forward_origins" '"all"',
"pglogical.replication_set_names" 'custom_set',
"relmeta_cache_size" '-1', pg_version '150007', pglogical_version
'2.4.2', pglogical_version_num '20402', pglogical_apply_pid '13850')

I have several such errors. I assume that they might be related to my disabling the subscription (the first step to cleanup the replication).
Workers related information
The Azure configuration related to the workers is as follows:

In the logs I could only find worker-related information such as (not sure if it is related to the replication or not):

pg_qs: qs bgworker: worker woke up and performed operations, with
query data store as on pg_qs: qs bgworker: worker finished
successfully in 85.484192 ms, with query store as on,
default_transaction_read_only as off and having_schema as true manager
worker [10790] at slot 1 generation 2 detaching cleanly

Message table schema and indexes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Message"
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "RequestRef" uuid NOT NULL,
    "RefId" uuid,
    "ReasonCode" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "StatusCode" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "IsChargeable" boolean NOT NULL,
    "DestinationIdentifier" character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "DestCode" character varying(2) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Sender" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "SenderTypeCode" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Sector" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Vars" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Network" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "IsPiiRemoved" boolean NOT NULL,
    "SentTimestamp" timestamp with time zone,
    "CreateTimestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "UpdatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "OrderNo" bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    "NormalizedDestinationIdentifier" character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    "MsgDirection" character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown'::character varying,
    "CharSet" citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::citext,
    "ConvId" uuid,
    "IsFixedLine" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "IsViewed" boolean,
    "ViewedBy" uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Message" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: IX_Message_ConvId

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public."IX_Message_ConvId";

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Message_ConvId"
    ON public."Message" USING btree
    ("ConvId" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: IX_Message_NormalizedDestinationIdentifier_Sender

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public."IX_Message_NormalizedDestinationIdentifier_Sender";

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Message_NormalizedDestinationIdentifier_Sender"
    ON public."Message" USING btree
    ("NormalizedDestinationIdentifier" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, "Sender" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: IX_Message_RequestRef

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public."IX_Message_RequestRef";

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_Message_RequestRef"
    ON public."Message" USING btree
    ("RequestRef" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

Besides DataDog integration, I am measuring the replication delay for inserts using the following two Message table columns in the replica:
    <all columns from the main are here, including CreateTimestamp>

    "ReplicatedTimestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'::text),
    "InsertReplicationDelay" bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((EXTRACT(epoch FROM ("ReplicatedTimestamp" - "CreateTimestamp")) * (1000)::numeric))::bigint) STORED,

For the built-in replication, at about 150 inserts/second in the Message table, 99.9% of the values in InsertReplicationDelay are less than 80ms (databases on the same database instance for now).

Did you have a chance to look at what Postgres writes in its log file?

@mustaccio fortunatelly, the server logs download was active and I could download and inspect them. I added to the post what I think might be relevant.

Adding a larger section of the log would be more helpful; based on just this one line it is hard to say anything conclusive. It could be just the result of a benign WAL sender timeout

I'm surprised that there are no messages in the log from the subscriber replication workers. Are your worker settings sufficient?

@mustaccio I have added extra details about the workers. As a side note, I have fell-back to using the builtin replication and have indeed noticed a lot of worker-related activity in the logs which is not present when trying to use pglogical instead.

What is the version of pglogical in use?

Please make this more repeatable and quantitative.  What is the definition of the "Messages" table?  What are the indexes? How big is the data going into it?  When you say you expect sub-100ms, that is per what?  Per row?  Per entire table? Can you reproduce this with community PostgreSQL (not Azure)?

@jjanes I have added the information you have requested. I am directly using Azure PostgreSQL because I could not setup pglogical in either my dev machine (Windows 11) or docker container. I know that replication is supposed to work between two different database instances and I am wondering if using the same instance can lead to such behaviour (for example, the buiiltin replication fails if a custom slot is not explicitly created).

The definition of one of the replica-only columns, "InsertReplicationDelay", depends on another column which doesn't exist, "CreateTimestamp".  If I change it to instead use ""CreatedAt" then I start getting segfaults, which must be a bug in the pglogical code, but I doubt it is related to the issue you are having.

@jjanes yes, I have fixed that. This would have led to a clear replication error mentioning the missing column anyway.

This might be some Azure-specific behavior.  The "stock" pglogical doesn't support generated columns, and in my hands I get a completely broken set up, not just a slow one.  If I omit the generated column, then I don't see any slowness although it is possible I'm not measuring it in a way compatible with the way you do.

@jjanes The generated column exists only in the replica, not in the main. I will also try without it, but it worked fine for the built-in replication (both locally and in Azure). Btw - in your setup, did you use the same database instance for both main and replica databases or different database instances?

Yes, I had both databases on the same PostgreSQL instance.  And yes, the generated column is only on the replica.  pglogical seems to be basically unmaintained at this point (except that Azure apparently is doing some kind of undisclosed maintenance for it?), so it is not surprising it has errors which built-in replication does not.
